# Nunjucks Templating Two column layout

Tags: html, templates, reusability, nunjucks

How can I do this in Nunjucks? I have a main layout file that defines the HTML page with the  and all file includes and meta data. Then I have a homepage template that extends layout. In this homepage, I would like to include a reusable two column layout that I will also use on other pages. Inside the left column and right column, I will nest other various components. How can I achieve this in my nunjucks templates allowing the two-column HTML to be used on various pages while still allowing me to nest different component in the columns differently for each page?

I tried nesting blocks, but could not get this to work. I am new to nunjucks, so I am unfamiliar with the syntax.

Here is what I have so far, but this is not ideal because I would currently have to duplicate and paste in the two column markup into every page:

[image]